# Can anybody help me with tkinter customization of a Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Hy all,

I have a code that works very well it is a Notebook with buttons on right that close the tabs on each tab. The problems is I want to put this buttons on left and I couldn't understand the code that does this magic. This was my idea because the buttons disappear when many tabs are opened, but if you have other idea I appreciate.  Here is the code:

```
### CustomNotebook ###
class CustomNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
"""A ttk Notebook with close buttons on each tab"""

__initialized = False

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.__initialized:
        self.__initialize_custom_style()
        self.__initialized = True
    
    self.singleton = singleton.TabSingleton()

    kwargs["style"] = "CustomNotebook"
    ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.configure(width=600)
    self._active = None

    self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_close_press, True)
    self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_close_release)

    self.popup_menu = self.__create_context_menu()
    RightClickEventListener(self, self.show_context_popup)
    
def __create_context_menu(self):
    m = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
    m.add_command(label="Close", command=lambda : self.__close_tab(self.popup_index))
    m.add_command(label="Close Other Tabs", command=lambda : self.__close_others(self.popup_index))
    m.add_command(label="Close Tabs to the Right", command=lambda : self.__close_right(self.popup_index))
    return m

def size(self):
    return len(self.tabs())

def __close_right(self, index):
    total_tabs = len(self.tabs())
    if index + 1 == total_tabs:
        return

    for remove_index in reversed(range(index + 1, total_tabs)):
        self.__close_tab(remove_index)

def __close_left(self, index):
    for _ in range(0, index):
        self.__close_tab(0)

def __close_others(self, index):
    self.__close_right(index)
    self.__close_left(index)

def show_context_popup(self, event):
    try:
        self.popup_index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
    except:
        ### no tab selected
        return

    try:
        self.popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    finally:
        self.popup_menu.grab_release()

def add_riser(self, id):
    if id.startswith('proj'):
        if not self.__is_riser_already_open(id):
            self.__create_riser_frame(id)
        else:
            tab_id = singleton.tabs_opened.index(id)
            self.select(tab_id=tab_id)
            
    elif id.isnumeric():
        print('Handle this id', id)

def __is_riser_already_open(self, id):
    return id in singleton.tabs_opened

def __create_riser_frame(self, id):
    tab_id =len(self.tabs())

    riser = singleton.risers[id]
    frame = Frame(self, bg='#fff')
    Label(frame, text=riser['name']).pack()
    self.add(frame,text=riser['name'])
    self.select(frame)
    singleton.tabs_opened.insert(tab_id, id)

def on_close_press(self, event):
    """Called when the button is pressed over the close button"""
    
    element = self.identify(event.x, event.y)

    if "close" in element:
        index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
        self.state(['pressed'])
        self._active = index
        return "break"

def on_close_release(self, event):
    """Called when the button is released"""
    if not self.instate(['pressed']):
        return

    element =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)
    if "close" not in element:
        # user moved the mouse off of the close button
        return

    index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))

    if self._active == index:
        self.__close_tab(index)

    self.state(["!pressed"])
    self._active = None

def close_active(self):
    index = self.index(self.select())
    self.__close_tab(index)

def __close_tab(self, index):
    self.forget(index)
    self.singleton.close_tab(index)
    self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

def __initialize_custom_style(self):
    style = ttk.Style()
    self.images = (
        tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
            R0lGODlhCAAIAMIBAAAAADs7O4+Pj9nZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
            d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
            5kEJADs=
            '''),
        tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
            R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2cbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxiH5BAEKAAQALAAA
            AAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU5kEJADs=
            '''),
        tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
            R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAOUqKv9mZtnZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
            d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
            5kEJADs=
        ''')
    )

    style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
                        ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                        ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"), border=8, sticky='')
    style.layout("CustomNotebook", [("CustomNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
    style.layout("CustomNotebook.Tab", [
        ("CustomNotebook.tab", {
            "sticky": "nswe",
            "children": [
                ("CustomNotebook.padding", {
                    "side": "top",
                    "sticky": "nswe",
                    "children": [
                        ("CustomNotebook.focus", {
                            "side": "left",
                            "sticky": "nswe",
                            "children": [
                                ("CustomNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ("CustomNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                            ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ]
    })
])

### TabPage ###
class TabPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, id):
        super().__init__(root, bg='purple')
        self.id = id

class SingletonMeta(type):
"""
This is a thread-safe implementation of Singleton.
"""

_instances = {}

_lock: Lock = Lock()
"""
We now have a lock object that will be used to synchronize threads during
first access to the Singleton.
"""

def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Possible changes to the value of the `__init__` argument do not affect
    the returned instance.
    """
    # Now, imagine that the program has just been launched. Since there's no
    # Singleton instance yet, multiple threads can simultaneously pass the
    # previous conditional and reach this point almost at the same time. The
    # first of them will acquire lock and will proceed further, while the
    # rest will wait here.
    with cls._lock:
        # The first thread to acquire the lock, reaches this conditional,
        # goes inside and creates the Singleton instance. Once it leaves the
        # lock block, a thread that might have been waiting for the lock
        # release may then enter this section. But since the Singleton field
        # is already initialized, the thread won't create a new object.
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
    return cls._instances[cls]
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code, and try to reduce it down to a [mcve]. It seems like there's a lot of code that isn't necessary to reproduce this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the order of the label and the button in the layout:

```
...
style.layout("CustomNotebook.Tab", [
    ...
    "children": [
        ("CustomNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
        ("CustomNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
    ]
    ...
])
```